# Dynamic segments other than id in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around dynamic segments and I want to be able to use a slug or other property instead of the id. When I can get things working it feels like a fluke. (I'm using ember 2.7+)

I've been looking at the following sources/threads for ideas:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/ember_data/linking_to_slugs  (1.10)
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/slugs-for-replacing-id-path-for-dynamic-segments

I plan on using ember-data, but I want to ensure I'm in control - and so I don't want to use the :post_slug / underscore style that has some built in magic that I want to avoid.

Here is an [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/41ecbfd2d82a1541965b00b2c8065e24?openFiles=templates.cats.index.hbs%2C&route=%2Fcats)
Here are [step-by-step commits in a github repo](https://github.com/sheriffderek/dynamic-segments-tests/commits/queryRecord)

### My thought process

1. Conceptually, lets say I need a list of cats - so I need to describe the model for what a 'cat' is.

*models/cat.js*

```
import Model from "ember-data/model";
import attr from "ember-data/attr";

export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  slug: attr('string')
});
```

2. define where the dynamic segment will be in the url. I'm going to use catId to prove a point instead of cat_id or :id like most of the tutorials I've seen. For this example, I'm also writing an actual app structure instead of the smallest router possible - to test the edges of this. + what if I needed something like this later: animals.com/cats/:catId/best-friend/:dogId

*router.js*

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('cats', { path: '/cats' }, function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/' }); // list of cats
    this.route('cat', { path: '/:catId' }); // cat spotlight
  });
});
```

3. pull in the catData into the store ~ in the /cats route

*routes/cats.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const catData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dolly',
    slug: 'dolly'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'kitty cat',
    slug: 'kitty-cat'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Cleopatra',
    slug: 'cleo'
  }
];

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return catData;
    // return this.get('store').findAll('cat'); // with mirage or live api
  }
});
```

Update from comments:

> I do not believe that you can use queryRecord with your test data.
>   Ember data plays dumb with query and queryRecord; it doesn't assume
>   anything about your data and just passes the call on to your server.

~ @xcskier56

So this kinda blows my twiddle as is. The git repo example is Mirage.

4. create the templates... + set up the 'cat' route. The records are in the *store*... right? so I should be able to 'peek' at them based on id. The docs use `params` - but -

> Ember will extract the value of the dynamic segment from the URL for
>   you - and pass them *as a hash* to the model hook as the first argument

: ~ and so the params object name isn't special and could really be anything you wanted... and is just replaced with a hash - so to that point / I'm using 'passedInThing' just to assert control over the confusing conventions (many tutorials use *param* instead of *params*)

*routes/cats/cat.js*

```
model( passedInThing ) {
  return this.store.peekRecord('cat', passedInThing.catId );
} // not going to happen - but in theory...

model( passedInThing ) {
  return this.store.queryRecord('cat', { slug: passedInThing.catId } );
}
```

5. At this point, I should be able to navigate to the url /cats/2 - and the `2` should get passed through the model hook - to the query. "Go get a 'cat' with an id of 2" --- right???  ((the twiddle example uses a hard-coded set of catData - but in my other attempts I'm using mirage with a combination of fixtures and dynamic slugs:  https://github.com/sheriffderek/dynamic-segments-tests/commits/queryRecord

6. Typing in the segment works - but for `link-to` helpers I need to pass in the explicit `cat.id`

```
{{#link-to 'cats.cat' cat.id}}
  <span>{{cat.name}}</span>
{{/link-to}}
```

**7.** I can get all that working - but I don't want an ID in the URL. I want `cats/cleo` with the 'slug' ~ in theory I can just switch `catId` for `catSlug` and `cat.id` to `cat.slug` etc - but that is not the case. I've seen many tutorials outlining this but they are outdated. I've tried passing in `{ slug: params.slug }` and every combo of find query and peek etc. Sometimes the url will work but the model wont render - or the opposite.

**8.** This seems like 101 stuff. Can anyone explain this to me? Oh wise emberinos - come to my aid!

### UPDATES

- [A nice video showing how to use `serialize()` in this case](https://embermap.com/video/friendly-urls-with-slugs)
- There is supposedly an example coming to the Ember tutorial, but I haven't seen it land yet.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this same issue, and AFIK there is not a way to handle this without querying the server. While this is old and the code is a little out dated the logic still stands. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/use-slug-for-page-routes-id-for-store-find/6443/12

What I have done is to use `store.queryRecord()` and then my server is able to return a record fetched via a slug.

This is what the route would look like:

```
model: function (params) {
  return this.store.queryRecord('cat', {slug: params.catSlug})
}
```

This will enable you to not expose the ID in the url, but it will issue a query to the store every single time that the model gets hit. There seems to be some discussion of caching `query` and `queryRecord` in ember-data, but nothing working yet.

- https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1966

Other helpful resources:

- [How to cache query result in ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009059/how-to-cache-query-result-in-ember-data)
- [Cache a record when using Query Params in the call? Ember-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803388/cache-a-record-when-using-query-params-in-the-call-ember-data)

Comment: Regarding the 'peek' - Here is a twiddle a kind soul put together to show a way to get a peek-like queryRecord: ember-twiddle.com/538e9b1437442c2fd34f226c710777bd

Comment: Regarding the slug in general - (I'm totally OK hitting the server as long as it works) 1. this.route('cat', { path: '/:catSlug' }); 2. {{#link-to 'cats.cat' cat.slug}} 3. return this.store.queryRecord('cat', {slug: params.catSlug}) These three things are the only moving parts right? Is the problem that I can't do this with static data for my test purpose? - because even when I use queryRecord things aren't as I expect.

Comment: Correct I do not believe that you can use queryRecord with your test data. Ember data plays dumb with `query` and `queryRecord`; it doesn't assume anything about your data and just passes the call on to your server.


If you want to keep testing this with `queryRecord` I'd recomend looking into  http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/. It will allow you to create a simple server in ember that you can then respond to the server query with

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have a test setup with mirage already. I'll try what you suggest there and see if it works. I also have a live API setup too - but was trying to get the test scenario as lean as possible.

Comment: Shoot! I just checked my mirage version and I had it setup with queryRecord but I still get this: "Error while processing route: cats.cat Assertion Failed: Expected the primary data returned by the serializer for a `queryRecord` response to be a single object but instead it was an array"

Comment: "Successful request: GET /cats?{"slug":"mr-butterkins"}"

Comment: @sheriffderek, you are returning an array when you should return an object. To solve this you can use `queryRecord` and do: `... then((res) function() {res.get('firstObjtect') ...})`. That will work.

Comment: I'm unsure why it's returning an array. When I log params I get: params:  Object {catSlug: "mr-butterkins"}  --- that being said, the array seems to be all of the cats... so grabbing firstObject works - but only pulls the model data of the firstObject for all of them. EDIT... nm - I was playing with just query in that case to try something... : /

Comment: This seems to be turning into a question of its own. If you can ask this as another question and post your `mirage/config.js` file I'd be happy to help.